# How to correct the array indexes so that the correct value is selected

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have to input a number that determines the size of my array and then the following numbers added are the actual values to consider, and then take the last two integers and use them as the indexes of the Array with which I find the particular numbers I want to multiply together.

For example I will input 9 3 7 10 18 70 6 4 3 5 where the 9 says I will have 9 integers following it and 3 and 5 are the indexes I want the values of. Those are 10 and 70 so my result should be 700.

Scanner, X and Y are declared elsewhere.

```
int intNumber = in.nextInt();
array = new int[intNumber];
for (int a = 0; a < intNumber; a++) {
      array[a] = in.nextInt();
      x = array[array[array.length-1]];
      y = array[array[array.length-2]];
} 
System.out.println(x * y);
```

Instead of looking at indexes 3 and 5 and using those values, it is going to indexes 4 and 6 and using them. I believe it's because my array truly begins with the 3 after 9 but how can I account for that while still getting the correct indexes from the end of the array? The three should be at index 1 and it's actually at 0 which is shifting all my values. I can't add the 9 into the array because I need it to be separate in order to know how many integers it will hold but I don't really know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working the way it's supposed to.
If you want to start the array at index 1 change the variable a to 1 and also increase the size of array by 1.

```
int intNumber = in.nextInt();
array = new int[intNumber+1];
for (int a = 1; a <=intNumber; a++) {
  array[a] = in.nextInt();

} 
 x = array[array[array.length-1]];
 y = array[array[array.length-2]];
System.out.println(x * y);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help ! You actually proactively helped with another issue I would have which was moving my variable outside of my for loop so thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry your question was slightly confusing, but something that will help you out in Java, is that arrays are 0 indexed. So if I manually built your array it would look like this:

```
array[0] = 3;
array[1] = 7;
array[2] = 10;
array[3] = 18;
array[4] = 70;
array[5] = 6;
array[6] = 4;
array[7] = 3;
array[8] = 5;
```

If I am understanding your question, then I think your answer is to do

```
x = array[array[array.length-1] - 1];
y = array[array[array.length-2] - 1];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The array should be a literal length of 10. The first supplied number (9) is included within the array as first element. Why the additional **-1** to acquired index values for **x** and **y**?

Comment: Yeah I guess it wasn't clear what exactly I was asking. Basically, my code worked perfectly fine for what I was telling it to do, it just wasn't matching up with what my assignment needed. Thank you for the help!